# Kibana, Logstash for big data enviornment

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, bigdata, logstash, kibana

Can we use `Logstash` and `Kibana` for big data analytics?

I will be using Hadoop to store my data. Before trying anything, I want to know if someone already tried this.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your data?

For now, I use Logstash + ElasticSearch + Kibana to analyze over 50 GB of log data.

Elasticsearch also has integration with Hadoop. 
Check this link: http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/hadoop/

Comment: Around 100-125 GB of data will be accumulate at my server for a week , i want to analyse the same. I have gone through link that you have shared, that perfectly fine . 
I am looking for some more insights from you setup , like system performance for your set up , also your system configuration . 
Are you experiencing any sort of delays while putting various filters in Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually put HDFS + ElasticSearch + Kibana + Logstash to work using Hive. It works pretty well.
Although if you are trying to load data from ElasticSearch into Hive, without declaring the data types properly, you may get NULL values on your data.

--- Hive Coonection ---
Ensure the `es-hadoop-hive-2.0.2.jar` and `es-hadoop-2.0.2.jar` files are located in your Hive directory.

Follow the documentation on ElasticSearch website for more details.

Answer (score 0):

125GB of (guessing) 1k documents over a week is about 200/sec, which is no problem for any logstash/elasticsearch configuration to index.

Go find yourself 6 machines:

- three elasticsearch data nodes, with 64GB of RAM each.
- three machines that run elasticsearch master nodes (with much lower RAM requirements).  These could also be client nodes (used for indexing and search requests), and could run logstash and kibana is you beefed them up a little bit.